# Separate database read/write paths in Dropwizard/JDBI

Tags: database, scaling, dropwizard

I'd like to direct all write queries to a primary database and all read queries to a replica database *without having to modify every DAO* in the system or have two DAOs for most things—I'd like it to happen transparently behind the scenes.

My first thought was to try and intercept the `@SqlQuery` and `@SqlUpdate` annotations, but I'm wondering if there is a more built-in approach.

This seems to be a common way to scale relational databases, but my searches didn't turn up anything substantial. Anyone ever get this working?

Comment: Are you using JDBI? With SQL Objects?

Comment: JDBI with mappers to pull values from result sets to POJOs.

Comment: If you have a separate read replica, MariaDB driver can detect a read replica and can redirect queries accordingly. Tried MariaDB with AWS Aurora MySQL with read replicas.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like ProxySQL would also be able to do this behind the scenes for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different database connections you will have to create `DBI` instances using different configurations. Then you will have to split each existing DAO into a DAO for read and one for write operations. Create an instance of each DAO using

```
ReadDAO readDAO = dbi.onDemand(ReadDAO.class);
WriteDAO writeDAO = dbi.onDemand(WriteDAO.class);
```

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid precisely this, though I didn't make that clear in the initial post...